# Make sbt constant having a dependency included in Test and Integration Test

Tags: scala, testing, sbt, integration-testing

How to state that a library should be used for `Test` and `IntegrationTest` without falling back to strings like `"test,it"`?

Example:

```
  "org.scalamock" %% "scalamock-scalatest-support" % "3.3.0" % Test,
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % scalaTestVersion % "test,it" //<- how to make this safer
```

Answer (score 1):

The safest way I found to code that is using a Seq and mkstring like that:

```
"dependency" % Seq(Test, IntegrationTest).mkString(",")
```

It is a workaround and I'm not sure it's a good practice to have that kind of logic in a build.